# PHP-unable to download a .pdf file from database , file content is stored in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

i have written a code in php which will echo a pdf file.whenever i am trying to echo that pdf,the browser page is changing into gray colors and the loading icon at the bottom left side corner is appearing and after that it fails to show that pdf file.

what i can assure you that code upto fetching the data from databse is perfect.there is no error or mistake.after fetching the data i have used following headers to echo that file.i am not sure about these headers.

```
$mimetype = 'application/pdf';
$disposition = 'attachment';
header('Content-type: $mimetype');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="$question"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-length: ' . strlen($question));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
echo "$question";
```

NOTE: I have used .pdf extension in content-decomposition.but that was not fruitful to me.also used readfile() function and it was also not helpful to me. Can anyone tell me what's wrong there?

Comment: Does `$question` contain the filename or the file contents?  You've used it two different ways.

Comment: yes..it contains the file

Comment: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected. in

Comment: this error is showing now

Comment: That's because you've defined the filename as *the entire contents of the PDF file*.  You need to supply the filename in `filename="some_file.pdf"`, *not the contents of the file`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main reason why `page is changing into gray colors` is that the browser is unable to detect content type correctly.

Try this:

```
header("Content-type: $mimetype");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$question.'"'); // Filename should be there, not the content
```

Instead of :

```
header('Content-type: $mimetype');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="$question"');
```

It seems that you have invalid quotes, so the content type is not specified correctly.

**EDIT**

To clear out, let's assume that `$question` is the binary PDF content.
That is what your code should be:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=anything.pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
echo $question;
```

**ERRORS EXPLAINED**

Let's discuss your original code and your errors.

```
$mimetype = 'application/pdf';
$disposition = 'attachment';

// First error: you have single quotes here. So output is 'Content-type: $mimetype' instead of the 'Content-type: application/pdf'
header('Content-type: $mimetype');

// Second error. Quotes again. Additionally, $question is CONTENT of your PDF, why is it here?
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="$question"');


header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

// Also bad: strlen() for binary content? What for?
header('Content-length: ' . strlen($question));


header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
echo "$question";
```

**ONE MORE EDIT**

> i have another query...i want to change the filename into $year.pdf..$
>   year may have values like 2007..how can i do that???

Try this :

```
$year = '2013'; // Assign value
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.$year.'.pdf');
```

Instead of:

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=anything.pdf');
```

Comment: Make sure file is generated correctly and there is no output before and after code you have showed us.

Comment: i have used file name but still not working...it's already 6 hours ..am working on it

Comment: yeah ...i went through these checkings many time..there is no such errors

Comment: value of strlen() will be what??..data or file name

Comment: Forget it for now. Remove. I made it as simple as possible. I have left only required code.

Comment: not it's in a loop of "sending req to localhost " and ""waiting for local host..nothing more than that..

Comment: yeah..strange..surprising..but at the end..in dark

Comment: i have another query...i want to change the filename into $year.pdf..$ year may have values like 2007..how can i do that???

Comment: @RitabrataGautam I have updated the answer to explain things that you have asked.

Comment: thanks for the explanation...it will be kind of u if u  answer my last comment

Comment: i have another query...i want to change the filename into $year.pdf..$ year may have values like 2007..how can i do that???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26168/discussion-between-e-error-and-ritabrata-gautam)

Comment: now most irrelevant question..am sorry if u feel disturbed..what's your facebook id??..wanna be your friend?